# Change placement of dialogs when dialogs are thrown by OS?

Tags: windows-8.1, display, multiple-monitors

I'm working with Windows 8.1, x64 (fully patched). Whenever Windows throws a dialog, it does so off-screen:

[image]

I'm in a dual monitor configuration, and the display giving me trouble is the primary display. The secondary display is to the left and above the primary display:

[image]

I've rebooted numerous times, and I even updated the Intel drivers for the machine. Neither have been helpful.

How do I instruct Windows to stop throwing dialogs off-screen? Or, how do I instruct Windows to throw a dialog at a particular location?

### -----

Here are some related KB's that don't fix the problem for my configuration:

- [Part of a pop-up window appears off-screen in Internet Explorer 8](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974537)
- [Some Programs Are Displayed Off the Screen](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/181691)

There's actually Microsoft Connect bug reports, but they were closed as *"Won't Fix"*. See, for example, [Connection Dialog Appears Off Screen](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/724909/connection-dialog-appears-off-screen). You gotta love replies like:

> Thanks for contacting Microsoft. We have been able to reproduce this
>   issue, but have decided not to improve the behavior at this time since
>   this is a relatively benign problem.

Comment: Remove one of the displays.  This will reset where the dialogs are being displayed.

Comment: Does it behave the same way while in Safe Mode?  In normal mode, If you reposition where Windows thinks the monitors are in relation to each other (like put them side by side) does it still throw them off-screen?

Comment: @ Ramhound - no joy. More broken shít from Redmond. Microsoft is getting to be as bad as Apple by unleashing untested and broken shít on the unsuspecting public.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - I don't know. Who works in Safe Mode? I work in regular mode.

Comment: So you don't want to troubleshoot in attempts to actually solve the problem? No problem then, I'm out!

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - no problem, and thanks for the help. Microsoft should troubleshoot this shít. I'm just interested in the solution. The solution I came up with is how to tell Windows *exactly* where to place the Window since the OS seems incapable of doing it on its own. Hence, my question.

Comment: Jeffrey, Your attitude sucks.  This doesn't normally.  This is a localized issue.

Comment: @Ramhound - Microsoft's software sucks. Its one problem after another. Its affecting my job performance, which puts me in a bad mood (look at all my questions recently). I pay good money for this broken crap.  If you want to see my attitude improve, Redmond should improve their software.

Comment: @jww - Good Luck.  Microsoft software is willingly purchased by millions of people. My thoughts on the quality of Apple's software is exactly the same.  **I cannot accept helping somebody who wants people to die.**  It doesn't take very much of an effort to know what the initials JWW stand for.

Comment: @Ramhound - like I said: Microsoft said "f--k me", and I say "f--k them" right back. I have no problem wishing ill-will on someone who steals from me or cheats me. With the Microsoft executives gone, we have a chance that the new executives will actually fix the problem.

Comment: @ Ramhound - as for JWW, what's your point? My name is on the desktop screenshot accompanied with this question. It should be in my profile, too. Here's my email in case you want it: nonloader, gmail address. I don't hide behind anonymity.

Comment: @Ramhound - I'm glad you're having a better experience then me. For me, its a constant problem, not a one-off problem. I've been suffering this problem for months now.

Comment: @jww - I didn't actually see a name in the screenshot and still do not see one.

Comment: I don't really care what your name is, you wished a group of people would die, that's not acceptable as a human being

Comment: @Ramhound - unfortunately, they stole from me or cheated me. They made the decision to do it, so tough  shít about their luck. I wish it on politicians who take bribes and then peddle their influence, too. There's lots of people who should go away. The world would will be a better place for those of us who remain and are forthright in out lives and business dealings.

Answer (score 1):

You can restore the location of an application's window or any dialog by using the following method

1. Right-click on the window caption on the taskbar, or select it and use Alt+Space.
2. If the Restore option is available, select it to pop the window out of minimized or maximized state.
3. Choose the Move option.
4. Hit an arrow key.
5. Move (the window) with the mouse.